# matplotlib: Saving a subplot axes array without showing figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to save multiple subplots using `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`. The problem I'm facing is that the figures are displayed after saving them, which clogs up memory and crashes the program. I don't want the subplots to be displayed, only saved. I suspect this is due to calling `Axes.imshow` for the `Axes` object but I don't know how else to add images to the subplot. I've looked at the docs for `pyplot` and the `Axes` class but haven't found a solution.

https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html

https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes

Here is a relevant snippet from my code. When I call the function `save_images` the figure gets displayed.

```py
# imgs is a numpy array of images

def save_images(folder, name, imgs, grid_size=3):
    f, axarr = plt.subplots(grid_size, grid_size, figsize=(15,15))
    for i in range(grid_size):
        for j in range(grid_size):
            axarr[i,j].imshow(imgs[i*grid_size + j]
    name_path = os.path.join(folder, name)
    plt.savefig(name_path)
```

Again, the problem is that the subplots are displayed after saving which crashes the program after 20 figures (and thus 20 figures are shown). I only wish to save those figures.

Comment: Perhaps add `plt.close()` after `savefig`?

Comment: When running code as python script, this would not happen (you would need to call `plt.show()` or `plt.draw()` for that). You seem to be using some interactive environment. Depending on which one that is, there might be a couple of options.

Comment: Yep, that does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I sent my script to a cluster where the job crashed with the error "tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display". I was puzzled as to why the image was displayed after calling the function `save_images` as it seemed like an unexpected behavior of `savefig`.

Comment: Although the problem persists when I send it to the cluster.

Comment: Import matplotlib.  Matplotlib.use(“agg”).   That will avoid the default GUI backend.